# JavaFX ListView items stack from bottom

Tags: listview, javafx-8

I'm new to JavaFX and was trying to implement a chat system. My problem is, I want to create an inverted list view which will be updating its items from bottom. In android it can be achieved by enabling "stack from bottom" like in [this post](http://gmariotti.blogspot.in/2013/07/quick-tips-for-listview-build-layout.html). How can this be achieved in JavaFX.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just keep adding new items at the 0th index in your ListView's items list.

```
listView.getItems().add(0, newItem);
```

**Sample App**

[image: reversed]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ListViewViewer extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        ListView<String> list = new ListView<>();
        ObservableList<String> items = list.getItems();
        items.add(0, "1");
        items.add(0, "2");
        items.add(0, "3");
        items.add(0, "4");

        stage.setScene(new Scene(list));
        stage.show();
    }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

---

If what you wanted was 1,2,3,4 rather than 4,3,2,1 as in the sample, then just add the new items to the items list without specifying an insertion index:

```
listView.getItems().add(newItem);
```

The items list is an observable list, so if you change the order of items in the observable list (e.g. you sort it or shuffle it), the updated item order will be immediately reflected in the ListView.

---

**Updated Answer based on Updated Question**

The article you link mentions Android functionality to add items to the bottom-most visible cell in a list (your "stack from bottom" functionality), such does not exist in the core JavaFX 8 libraries.  You could [file a feature request](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com) for such functionality if you wish.

Probably the best way to implement such functionality would be via a custom [Skin](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Skin.html) for ListView.  However, that would be quite a complicated task.

You can simulate the "stack from button" functionality by pre-populating the ListView with empty items, so new items are added to the bottom of the list (removing the dummy empty items as new items are added).  Here is a sample of such an approach:

[image: stackedfrombottom]

```
import javafx.animation.*;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class ListViewViewer extends Application {
    private static final int MAX_MESSAGES = 20;
    private static final int DISPLAYED_MESSAGES = 8;
    private static final int CELL_HEIGHT = 24;

    private int msgNum = 0;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        ListView<String> list = new ListView<>();
        ObservableList<String> items = list.getItems();
        for (int i = 0; i < DISPLAYED_MESSAGES; i++)  {
            items.add("");
        }
        list.setMinHeight(ListView.USE_PREF_SIZE);
        list.setPrefHeight(DISPLAYED_MESSAGES * CELL_HEIGHT + 2);
        list.setMaxHeight(ListView.USE_PREF_SIZE);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(list));
        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.show();

        simulateMessaging(list);
    }

    private void addMessage(ObservableList<String> items, String message) {
        if (items.get(0).equals("") || items.size() >= MAX_MESSAGES) {
            items.remove(0);
        }

        items.add(message);
    }

    private void simulateMessaging(ListView<String> list) {
        Timeline messageMaker = new Timeline(
                new KeyFrame(
                        Duration.seconds(1),
                        event -> {
                            addMessage(list.getItems(), nextMessage());
                            if (list.getItems().size() > DISPLAYED_MESSAGES) {
                                list.scrollTo(list.getItems().size() - 1);
                            }
                        }
                )
        );

        messageMaker.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);

        PauseTransition pause = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(2));
        pause.setOnFinished(event -> messageMaker.play());
        pause.play();
    }

    private String nextMessage() {
        return "msg " + msgNum++;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Adjust the sample as you need to get the exact functionality you require.

Comment: I tried your method but items are still on top of the listview. How can I change the alignment of items to the bottom like in usual chat programs?

Comment: I had edited the question to make my question more clear. Please refer.

Answer (score 0):

[Flowless](https://github.com/TomasMikula/Flowless), which is an alternative to `ListView`, let's you stack items from bottom. You just need to set *gravity* to `REAR` when creating an instance:

```
VirtualFlow<String, ?> flow = VirtualFlow.createVertical(
        items, cellFactory, VirtualFlow.Gravity.REAR)
```

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who might find this as their issue, use

```
Collections.reverse(arrayList);
```

It's easy and just needs to be applied at the very end to completely reverse your array.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution.

```
    list.setRotate(180);
    list.setNodeOrientation(NodeOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
    entry.setRotate(180);
    entry.setNodeOrientation(NodeOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
```

and finally reverse your scroll for the list.